# Onkelos on Deut. 4:19

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, bowing-kneeling, vaeschanan, targumin

In [Devarim 4:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=72), Onkelos translates ונדחת as ותטעי and והשתחוית as ותסגוד.

First, what exactly is he trying to convey with ותטעי? I think of טעות as "whoops", and hopefully there's no serious damage, or at least none that can't be repaired. This does not seem to be the meaning of the Pasuk.

Second, does השתחוה not have an Aramaic cognate? Is סגיד the normal way he translates this? I see a couple of other references to it in my [Sokoloff](http://amzn.com/0801872332) [dictionaries](http://amzn.com/0801872340), so if it is the usual translation I'm just surprised I never noticed before.

Comment: ס.ג.ד is the usual translation of ש.ח.ה. We even say it once or twice when taking out the Torah.

Comment: heeshta7awayoh means prostration and in arabic and aramaic it is sjd. muslims call their prostration sajud, or egyptian arabic saghud.

Comment: @SethJ np.......

Comment: @SethJ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigd related

Answer (score 1):

Remember this is Aramaic - not Hebrew.

תטעי in Aramaic means to go on the wrong path. *To stray*, if you will.

I understand the Aramaic סגד to mean *worship*, whereas to bow, or להשתחוות is the main action of worshiping.

Answer (score 0):

טעות means a mistake - להטעות means to mislead.  He will be misled by the grandeur of the heavens at which he is looking up and begin to worship them.